# Does bash return anything when it runs a command?

Tags: bash

I was found the guide to test if there is a bug in Bash. Namely, when

```
x='() { :;}; echo VULNERABLE' bash -c x
```

does not return anything, it is vulnerable. But are there cases like in C that bash can return something but user won't see it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you are looking for the exit code but that is completely irrelevant here. The test you ran will print `VULNERABLE` to your terminal if the version of bash you are using is vulnerable. If you don't see it, you passed the test.

While programs can indeed return information that is not necessarily shown to the user, that is not relevant to the issue here. For example, to see the exit code of a program in bash, use the `$?` variable:

```
$ ls /tmp > /dev/null
$ echo $?
0
$ ls /nonexistent_directory  > /dev/null
ls: cannot access /nonexistent_directory: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
2
```

So yes, something can be returned that you don't see unless you ask for it but no, that does not mean that the test you ran could have failed.